# Socket.io's function socket.on only called once

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Trying to build a webapp that has two sets of dropdowns, the second is conditional on the first. This functionality works for the first selection, but if you change the first dropdown, the second one returns nothing. I've tracked the problem down to the Socket.on inside SubDropdown. Socket.on runs the first time, but doesn't update when the component is changed, despite its encapsulating function running.

React Component:

```
class SubDropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.select = this.select.bind(this);
        this.props
        this.state = {
            dropdownOpen: false,
            value: "Select",
            options: [],
            socket: socketIOClient("localhost:7000")
        };

    }

    toggle(){
        this.setState({
            dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
        });
    }
    pullFromSocket(){
        console.log(this.props.mainDropdownValue);
        this.state.socket.on(this.props.mainDropdownValue, (_options) => {
            _options = _options.data;
            this.state.options = [];
            // setting the color of our button
            Object.keys(_options).forEach(function(key) {
                this.addToOptions(_options[key])
            }.bind(this))
        })
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.pullFromSocket();
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.state.socket.close();
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){

        if(this.props.mainDropdownValue != prevProps.mainDropdownValue)
        {

            this.setState(({
                value: "Select",
                options: []
            }))
            this.pullFromSocket();
        }
    }
    addToOptions(option){
        console.log(option);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          options: prevState.options.concat(option),
        }))
    }
    select(event) {
        this.setState({
          dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen,
          value: event.target.innerText
        });


    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
            <DropdownToggle onChange={this.props.onChangeValue(this.state.value)} caret> {this.state.value}</DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>{
                this.state.options.map((option) => (
                    <DropdownItem onClick={this.select} key={option.id} value={option.dropdown_value}>{option.dropdown_value}</DropdownItem>
                ))}
            </DropdownMenu> 
            </Dropdown>
        );
    }
  }

  export default SubDropdown;
```

Node Server Below:

```
let map = new Map();
let columns = ""
let parseName = (name) => {
  return name.split(" ").join("_").toLowerCase();;
}
let loadColumns = async () => {
  columns =  await client.getItems('column_heading');
  columns.data.map(async (column) => {

      if(column.database_access){
        map.set(column.dropdown_value, await client.getItems(parseName(column.dropdown_value)));
      }
  })

}
loadColumns();

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('User connected')

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected')
  })
  //TODO: make one function for socket emit
  socket.emit('getOptions', columns);

  socket.emit('Artefact Type', map.get('Artefact Type'));

  socket.emit('Period', map.get('Period'));

  socket.emit('Inside or Outside Fort', map.get('Inside or Outside Fort'));

  socket.emit('Year Excavated', map.get('Year Excavated'));

  socket.emit('Shoe Construction Type', map.get('Shoe Construction Type'));

  socket.emit('Shoe Type', map.get('Shoe Type'));

  socket.emit('Shoe Style', map.get('Shoe Style'));

  socket.emit('Stud Pattern', map.get('Stud Pattern'));

  socket.emit('Sole Shape', map.get('Sole Shape'));

  socket.emit('Foot', map.get('Foot'));

  socket.emit('Spatial Definition', map.get('Spatial Definition'));

  socket.emit('Possible Owner',map.get('Possible Owner'));

  socket.emit('Markings', map.get('Markings'));

  socket.emit('Condition', map.get('Condition'));
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {s
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
console.log()
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 7000);
```

Comment: There are a lot of issues with this code. 1) You're mutating state a lot. never do `this.state.thing = []` for example. Always use `this.setState({ thing: [] })`. 2) `DropDownToggle.onChange` is being passed the _result of_ `this.props.onChangeValue`. Are you sure this is what you intend? 3) Storing 'live objects' on state. You should never do this b/c live objects can change state without calling `setState`. Instead, you should keep `socket` on `this`. If you need to trigger a state change off a live object, you should listen for events and change state in a callback with `this.setState`.

Comment: 4) `Object.keys` uses a plain function as a callback, but uses `this` in its body. `function`s in JS have their own `this`, overriding the `this` of `SubDropdown`. Use an `(key) => {}` arrow function instead to get `this` of subdropdown or `let that = this` and refer to `that` instead..

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will definitely change the code accordingly. The socket being in the state was creating the bug I encountered, but all of those are good points.